# When using Task Router to set-up a conference call, can I set no answer timeout, recording, and friendly name?

Tags: twilio-taskrouter, twilio-conference

I am currently using a Twilio function containing the following callback instruction to set up a conference call and this works fine, but I'm baffled trying to set a few options:

1. The Task Router Workflow has a reservation timeout of 20 seconds, but the reservation isn't timing out if the worker doesn't answer their phone within 20 seconds, can this be set up with the conference instruction? I tried adding `timeout: "20"`, but it didn't work.
2. The default conference name is the task SID, is it possible to add a friendly name when  issuing the conference callback? I tried adding `friendly_name: "Test"`, but it didn't work.

My callback code (which works) is:

```
callback(null, {
  instruction: "conference",
  conference_record: "true",
  timeout: "20",           // doesn't work
  friendly_name: "Test",   // doesn't work
  status_callback_url: "https://url.com",
  from: "+12223334444"
});
```